# Reversing 32bit integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying out a question which asked me to reverse a 32bit signed integer, I created this python program

```
input1=int(input("Enter the number: "))
binary=bin(input1).replace('0b','')
result=binary.zfill(32)
num=list(result)
num=num[::-1]
result=''.join(num)
ans=int(result,2)
print(ans)
```

This code passed one test case when the value of input1 was 2 but failed in second testcase, when the value of input1 was 1
Expected answer = -2147483648
My answer = 2147483648

What changes should I make in the code to make it pass second testcase ?

Comment: Where's that question from? Please provide the link so we can see what exactly they mean, and test potential solutions.

Comment: @KellyBundy This question was from a placement coding round and sorry for the lack of info about it. Unfortunately, the description was just reversing the 32bit integer and print the decimal value of it. Also there were no constraints/range provided in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the sign bit of the binary version of your number. You can do that by looking at the 0-indexed value of either your `num` variable or `result`.

```
input1 = int(input("Enter the number: "))
binary = bin(input1).replace('0b', '')
result = binary.zfill(32)
num = list(result)
num = num[::-1]
result = ''.join(num)
if num[0] == '0':
    ans = int(result, 2)
else:
    # flip the sign
    ans = -int(result, 2)

print(ans)
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? Wouldn't it make more sense to extend the sign bit?

Comment: I mean, when asked to "reverse a 32bit signed integer", I'd say the result should be a 32bit signed integer as well.

Comment: @KellyBundy That would make sense, but it's hard to say with only 1.5 test cases. Given the expected value of -2147483648 for an input of 1, I think they're just expecting the reverse of an odd number to be negative.

Comment: I rather think that's an unfortunate special case. For example for input 3, you compute -3,221,225,472, which isn't a 32bit signed integer. That seems undesirable to me. I think `int.from_bytes(2147483648 .to_bytes(4, 'big'), 'big', signed=True)` is a better explanation for that -2147483648 result.

Comment: @KellyBundy, or just use `ans |= -(ans & 1 << 31)`, or use `int(result[1:], 2)` and check sign bit later. Or don't include sign bit into num at all: `sign, *num = num[::-1]`. Any of this options is better, because it will return correct result.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes, those look equivalent, although I find mine clearer for the argument (and that was my reason for doing it that way).

Comment: @OlvinRoght Or rather not "clearer" but "more appropriate", as my point is that I'm not doing any calculations or so there, only force an interpretation of the bits as a signed value.

Comment: @KellyBundy, *any of this options **including yours** is better* :-) I'd prefer to leave only 31 bits, get integer value from them and add sign later if needed. Main thing I've tried to highlight is that this solution won't deal with overflow correctly.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I do agree but also have to acknowledge Bill's "it's hard to say with only 1.5 test cases", and the OP can't be bothered to clarify.

Comment: Well this question was from a placement coding round, since the other testcases were hidden and I can't really test the code provided to me by @BilltheLizard for the hidden test cases....but either way its working after considering num[0] as sign bit

Answer (score 0):

```
input1 = int(input("Enter the number: "))
binary = bin(input1 ).replace("0b","").zfill(32)
reverse = binary[::-1]
result = int(reverse,2)
print(result if reverse[0] == "0" else -result)
```

Comment: Using formatting instead of `bin()`, `str.replace()` and `str.zfill()` is much more compact and should have slightly better performance. `reverse = f"{input1:032b}"[::-1]`